# Delete Files in Sharepoint folder after x days

Tags: delete-file, power-automate

I am trying to figure out how to delete files from a sharepoint folder that are older than 7 days.

I found many solutions online to this problem, including here: https://www.enjoysharepoint.com/power-automate-delete-file-from-sharepoint/ and https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/deleting-files-automatically-after-3-months/m-p/2683088 .  None worked.

This is what I see in the Flow Runs Page, and the files are not removed from the folder.

[image]

Here are my steps:

[image]

This is what that function says:

[image]

Then I have this step:

[image]

I set the date difference to 0 just in case, even though the file in my test folder was created on April 6.  I also tried - 7 and -1 but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this via shareplum

cred = HttpNtlmAuth(username,password)

site = Site("sharepointsiteurl",version=Version.v365,auth=cred)

folder = site.Folder('Shared Documents/My Folder')

folder.delete_file('MyFile.csv')

or

refer this documentation =>
reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-visio/jj246911(v=office.15)

Answer (score 0):

I just recreated your requirement in my tenant.  You need to be careful as to the date format you use.

This basic expression to go back 7 days worked for me ...

[image: Variable]

```
getPastTime(7, 'Day')
```

***Note:** In my experience, you need to stick with working with UTC as that's what the created date is stored as.*

I tested the reverse of that to get all files that were created in the last **7** days.  I created two files and expected those to be returned.

You'll see I've still stuck with the name of the variable being less than but as you already know, all you *should* need to do is change the filter operand from `ge` to `le`.

[image: Step]

**Filter Applied**

[image: Filter Applied]

**Filter Omitted**

[image: Filter Omitted]

Comment: Thanks, @Skin but I still can't get this to work.  I tried both `Created ge '@{getPastTime(7,'Day')}'` and `Created le '@{getPastTime(7,'Day')}'` but no files are being deleted (all files in the folder were created more than 3 weeks ago.  Any idea?  Thanks!

Comment: Ahhhhh, ok but the deletion step is different to the filter step.  Can you show us a resulting output for your flow or something?